# ajax based multiple select layered Navigation with infinite product Scroll

Tags: layered-navigation, magento2.4, infinte-scroll

I am looking for an extension with these Features

1. Ajax Based Layered Navigation with Multiple select
2. Infinite product Scroll

please recommend any free or paid extension or group of an extension but they must have to be compatible together

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest https://amasty.com/infinite-scroll-for-magento-2.html and https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation-for-magento-2.html, they are kinda expencive but you wont find any free ones that are better.

Comment: thank you let me have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can check these extensions on github:

- https://github.com/magepow/magento2-layerednav
- https://github.com/magepow/magento2-infinitescroll

Please let us know if you test them and if you like them!

Comment: thank you let me have a look

Answer (score 0):

if you are using amasty shopby module for layered navigation then i suggest to use this extension for infinite scroll

**https://github.com/magepow/magento-2-infinite-scroll/**

in this module infinite scroll working when trigger "collectionUpdated".

so you just need to trigger "collectionUpdated" when you need to apply infinite scroll.
In amasty shopby module you need to add amShopbyAjax.js after ajax call or in success method of ajax.
Thank you.